# Integral does not converge for certain x

Tags: numerical-integration

I'm trying to evaluate an integral (which is a part of Caputo fractional derivative). Because it depends on both *x* and *t* I usually have a function wrapper that chooses a concrete *x* and things get going. I found that it's usually okay but when q is 0.7-9 or 1.7-9 for certain *x*'s the `NIntegrate` does not converge. (Here I put *x* as a rational because I found it helps in evaluation for some reason.)

Here is one random instance of this:

```
q = 0.8;
NIntegrate[D[Sech[t],{t, Ceiling[q]}] (x-t)^(Ceiling[q]-q-1), {t,0,x}] /. x->241/50
```

Another *x* to try can be 103/50.

I've tried changing `AccuracyGoal`, `MaxRecursion`, `Method` but not with much luck. I have feeling that with proper `Method` it will find a good answer. It's been giving me some answers that are unstable -- they depend on the chosen `Method`, other times it gives me a complex answer which shouldn't be true.

I also plotted the integrand for when *x* is 241/50 and up to that *x* it looks convergent so I don't know where the problem is.

Thanks!

Comment: Try changing variables to `u = x-t`

Comment: There is an integrable singularity at the right endpoint (`x`, that is) so it is not surprising there might be convergence issues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you can just change variables from `t` to `u = x - t`? For example:

```
q = .8;
foo[x_] := NIntegrate[
    Derivative[Ceiling[q]][Sech][x-u]u^(Ceiling[q]-q-1),
    {u, 0, x}
]

foo[241/50]
foo[103/50]
```

> -0.481131
>
> -1.71624

Comment: That's beautiful and it works! One question: why do the bounds go from 0 to x instead of x to 0? When t = 0, u = x, when t = x, u = 0

Comment: `du = -dt` so I included this sign change in the limits